# I need to print the second line on each query in other file

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I want to extract the Hit and No Hits ids from the my blast results.

for example my blast output contain:

```
> Query= TRINITY_DN109574_c0_g1_i1

Length=277
***** No hits found *****
Lambda      K        H        a         alpha
   0.318    0.134    0.401    0.792     4.96 
Gapped
Lambda      K        H        a         alpha    sigma
   0.267   0.0410    0.140     1.90     42.6     43.6 
Effective search space used: 749080088160

> Query= TRINITY_DN109587_c0_g1_i1

Length=312
***** No hits found *****
Lambda      K        H        a         alpha
   0.318    0.134    0.401    0.792     4.96 
Gapped
Lambda      K        H        a         alpha    sigma
   0.267   0.0410    0.140     1.90     42.6     43.6

> Query= TRINITY_DN109586_c0_g2_i1

Length=472

Sequences producing significant alignments:                          
                                    (Bits)  Value
protein LOC111635341 n=1...  104     1e-23
  UniRef90_UPI000C6CD8E3 uncharacterized protein LOC111632564 n=1...  103     1e-23
  UniRef90_UPI000C6CAADE uncharacterized protein LOC111636326 n=1...  103     3e-23
```

I wanted to be like below:

```
TRINITY_DN109574_c0_g1_i1          No hits
TRINITY_DN109587_c0_g1_i1          No hits 
TRINITY_DN109586_c0_g2_i1          Sequences producing significant alignments:
```

That mean I need to print the second line on each query in other file.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -E "/^$/d" file | awk '/> Query/{printf "%s\t", $3; nr[NR+2]}; NR in nr '
```

Output

```
TRINITY_DN109574_c0_g1_i1       ***** No hits found *****
TRINITY_DN109587_c0_g1_i1       ***** No hits found *****
TRINITY_DN109586_c0_g2_i1       Sequences producing significant alignments:
```

Walkthrough...

Your ID and hit line spacing varies depending on whether you get a hit or not but the spacing is made different only with an extra empty line, so if we remove all of the blank lines

```
sed -E "/^$/d" file
```

then the hit/no hit line is always 2 lines ahead of the query.
We then pipe `|` that into `awk` to find only those lines which are the start of a query

```
awk '/> Query/'
```

but we only want the 3rd (space separated) field `$3` from the query line, because that is your ID

```
awk '/> Query/{print $3}'
```

Whenever we find a regex match we also want to calculate the line number of the matching Hits line and store it in an array. I have called he array `nr` and the Hits line we are interested in is the current matching line `NR`+2

```
awk '/> Query/{print $3; nr[NR+2]}'
```

Finally add a second condition to check if a line `NR` that doesn't match the regex exists in our array `nr` and print it. Also changing the first `print` to `printf` so that Hits is output on the end of ID.

```
awk '/> Query/{printf "%s\t", $3; nr[NR+2]}; NR in nr;'
```

Note that this solution will break if the number added to `NR` goes past the next regex match.

Comment: Great explanation! +1

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed, we accumulate lines in the pattern space beginning from Query line, keep discarding the blank lines and print when 3 nonempty lines accumulated.

```
$ sed -e '
    :loop
        /\n.*\n/{
            s//\t/
            s/^> Query=//p
         }
         /^> Query=/!d
         $d;N
         s/\n$//
     bloop
' file
```

With Perl we slurp the file and get the query line, skip any blank lines, skip first nonempty line

```
$ perl -0777ne 'print "$1\t$2" while /^> Query=\h+(.*)\n\n*.*\n\n*(.*\n)/mg' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU grep in pcre mode we first extract the query line followed by 2 nonempty lines the intermediate empty lines can vary from zero to multiple.

```
$ < file grep -zoP '(?m:^> Query=\h+\K.*\n\n*(.*\n\n*){2})' |
    tr -d '\0' | tr -s '\n' |
    sed -e 'h;n;n;H;g;s/\n/\t/'
```

Another method using the range operator `...`:

```
$ perl -lane '
    $e = (/^> Query=/ && $c==0) ... (/\S/ && $c==2);
    next if !length($e) || !@F;
    $q = $F[2]       if $e == 1;
    print "$q\t$_" if $e =~ /E0/;
    $c = $c == 2 ? 0 : $c+1;
  ' file
```